# multiple regression with continuous and binary regressors

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, binary-data, continuous-data

How can I do a multiple regression if I have continuous and ordinal (binary) (eg. male and female) regressors.

Can I just add them like this lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=data)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes that is exactly what you would do. The software will then estimate an intercept along with a coefficient estimate for each variable.

Comment: But let's say one regressor is gender (1=male, 2=female). This is obviously a ordinal variable. Can I just include this variable into the code and interpret the output like a continous variable? How would I have to interpret the coefficient in this case?

Comment: It's binary. The most natural way to handle it is coding it as 0/1 so that whichever level corresponds to 0 will be included in the intercept and the estimate for it will be the difference between the two sexes.

Comment: What if I want to add more binary regressors (e.g. blue collar worker, white collar worker). Is there a dummy variable trap?

Comment: No, it's just the same. The intercept will be the expected value when all the variables are zero.

Comment: You might prefer (if x4 is binary) lm(y~x1+x2+x3+factor(x4)).  Then it will be converted to a 0/1 variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.